# Elasticsearch update query in spring project is deprecated

Tags: spring, elasticsearch

Elasticsearch update query in spring project is deprecate

I want to update a document in my spring application and a update code sends a deprecation warning api as below.

```
            UpdateQuery.builder(it)
                .withDocument(document)
                .build()    //  /{index}/_doc/{id}/_update   <- deprecated
```

```
#! Deprecation: [types removal] Specifying types in document update requests is deprecated, use the endpoint /{index}/_update/{id} instead.
```

How can I let my code to query with new update api ( `/{index}/_update/{id}` )?

Environment:

- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.6.7
- org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:4.3.4
- org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.15.2

Comment: I am having the same issue, did u find a solution? thanks

Comment: I couldn't find solutions and decided to use Opensearch Client for Opensearch Service.